# Objective-C Singleton Superclass?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to write a class that I can subclass to have an instant singleton.  Here's what I have so far.  It works until one of its subclasses calls another via sharedInstance which causes a huge loop that eventually runs out of memory.

Any ideas?

```
static NSMutableDictionary *sharedInstances = nil;

@implementation Singleton

+ (Singleton*)sharedInstance
{
    [Singleton initSharedInstances];
    Class myClass = [self class];
    Singleton * sharedInstance = [sharedInstances objectForKey:myClass];
    @synchronized(myClass)
    {
        if (sharedInstance == nil)
        {
            sharedInstance = [[myClass alloc] init];
            [sharedInstances setObject:sharedInstance forKey:myClass];
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

+ (void) initSharedInstances
{
    if (sharedInstances == nil)
    {
        sharedInstances = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to write a class that I can subclass to have an instant singleton. Here's what I have so far. It works until one of its subclasses calls another via sharedInstance which causes a huge loop that eventually runs out of memory.

This sounds like you are describing mutual-recursion. If subclass1 calls subclass2 and subclass2 calls subclass1 then you need to break the loop somewhere, just as with simple self-recursion.

Your `sharedInstance` itself should not cause infinite recursion unless the `init` method you invoke itself invokes `sharedInstance`...

Answer (score 7):

Why are you bothering with all this? If you're trying to enforce singleton behavior in the superclass by overriding `-retain`, `-release`, `-retainCount`, and `+allocWithZone:` then you're doing something completely unnecessary. Far more simple is just to provide a `+sharedInstance` method and do nothing else. If the user really wants to call `+alloc`/`-init`, they can, it just won't do them much good. For examples of this type of singleton in the frameworks, look at `NSUserDefaults` and `NSFileManager` (though in the case of the latter, these days Apple actually recommends you ignore the shared instance and alloc/init your own instances of `NSFileManager`).

In order to do this simple shared instance stuff, all you have to do is, in the singleton class, implement the following:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static MyClass sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        //sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
        sharedInstance = [MyClass alloc];
        sharedInstance = [sharedInstance init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: Completely agree;  I find all the overrides of methods in singleton classes to be generally rather silly.  It *might* *maybe* make sense in some class in a framework that'll be used by a myriad of people you don't know.  For your own stuff?  Keep it simple!!

Comment: I edited Kevin's code (hope you don't mind, Kevin?!) to provide a slightly more defensive pattern.  This is one of the few [only?] times where separating alloc from init can be useful;  if the `-init` method were to ever trigger a call to `+sharedInstance` the original code would deadlock on itself.

Comment: That's a good point. I've never written code where `-init` calls `+sharedInstance`, but I can certainly imagine it happening.